# Hashing Id column in MVC Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I was practicing MVC identity by using the features that Microsoft gives it Hash's the password for security reason which is understood.

Question is it was also Hashing the Id of each user.

Please see the image.

[image]

As the tables like AspNetUsers and other tables were created locally so now I want to use them in my localhost data base so how should I do it.

Do I have to generate the scripts of these tables then fire the query in SQL.

Like right clicking the table and using the option Open Table Definition.

Comment: What do you mean hashing the `ID` - The value shown in the image of your table is a `Guid`, not a hashed value

Comment: Oh my mistake right the GUID Id. Normally its Numeric value with Identity of 1.